# How to read bam (aligned information) file in SPARK?

Tags: python, apache-spark, bioinformatics

Recently I had to process bam files generated by BWA or other align tools on SPARK using Python or Scala, how to transform this binary file to RDD so that I can do some statistics on each read sequence and other information? Could anyone have some experience or give an example? I have read binaryRecords() function of PySpark and Spark-bam a little, which seems not work well.

Comment: Welcome! This question seems more appropriate for bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PySam in python.  See the docs here:
https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html